# Calculate available time slots for a bookable resource

Tags: javascript, datetime, reactjs, time, timezone

I have an application showing weekly (Mon-Sun) availability for a bookable resource.

In the view, adjacent to this calendar, the user can choose:
**A)** Length of desired slot to book (15 min/30min/60min/)
**B)** Timezone

Time slots always have the hour stroke as a reference point, i.e. if a user chooses to see 15min slots the possible starting points are only :00, :15, :30, :45.

Let's assume that the calendar internally has an availability between 07:23 and 09:10 tomorrow morning, and taking into account that the user might want to change timezone - what would be the most practical/logical way to manage calculation of available time slots for that time span?

Comment: have you solved it? I'm facing this right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [iCalendar RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) as implemented in the library [jkbrzt/rrule](https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule).  Check out the rrule library demo site [here](http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/).

For example, the rrule library code to achieve a rule that will produce the times you specify in your question (bear in mind this is for the 7th August 2016, not 'tomorrow', but I'm sure you can deal with that yourself) would look like:

```
let rrule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.HOURLY,
  dtstart: new Date(2016, 7, 7, 7, 12, 0),
  until: new Date(2016, 7, 7, 9, 10, 0),
  byminute: [0, 15, 30, 45]
})
```

You can then call:

```
rrule.all()
```

Which will yield an array of Dates for you to use as you see fit.